# how to destructure nested data from reactQuery/useQuery in next.js/react.js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js, axios, react-query

```
const {
  isLoading,
  data: products,
  refetch,
} = useQuery(["products"], () =>
  axios.get(
    `https://product-bazar.herokuapp.com/api/v1/public/product`
  )
);
```

How can I destruct data from data in this query operations ex:[data?.products]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `destructure` the nested data from `responded data`. But the better way to fetch data using `useQuery` is:

```
const fetchCartData = async () => {
const { data } = await axios.get(API.GET_ALL_CART_ITEMS, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
  },
});
if (data?.cart_data?.Items === undefined) {
  setCartLoading(false);
  return [];
} else {
  setCartLoading(false);
  return data?.cart_data?.Items ? data?.cart_data?.Items : [];
}};
```

And then use `useQuery` to fetch data through `fetchCartData()` function:

```
 const {
isLoading,
refetch,
data: cartData,
isError,
error} = useQuery(["cartData"], () => fetchCartData());
```